# How to grep string text in lua?

Tags: lua, grep

How can I get all the lines from string text that contain specific text?
for example:

```
local str = [[hello1 : hello01
hello2 : hello02
hello3 : hello03]]

print(some_func(str, "hello2"))
```

So I want to get in this case:

```
hello2 : hello02
```

I tried to use `print(string.find(str, "hello2"))` but i get only the first index and end index of `hello2` in this string (`18 23`).

we can think about it like a grep about string text (in bash, but i trying to do it in lua:

```
echo "hello1 : hello01
hello2 : hello02
hello3 : hello03" | grep "hello2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function:

```lua
function get_lines_with_text(inputstr, search)
    local t={}
    for str in string.gmatch(inputstr, "[^\n]*"..search.."[^\n]*") do
        table.insert(t, str)
    end
    return t
end
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/5jdH8d).

Here is a test using your string:

```lua
local str = [[hello1 : hello01
hello2 : hello02
hello3 : hello03]]

for _, line in pairs(get_lines_with_text(str, "hello2")) do
    print(line)
end
```

that outputs `hello2 : hello02`.

Comment: Hi, and if i know that exists only one line with this `search` word. how can i return only this line? i tried return `string.gmatch(str, "[^\n]*" .. search .. "[^\n]*")` but it's return `function: 0x55728d80c480`

Comment: @user123454321 It is much easier then, `str:match("[^\n]*hello2[^\n]*")` [would do that](https://ideone.com/tkY6G0). However, `grep` returns all occurrences, hence is  my answer.